# Removing a node in a Linked List using Links

Tags: python, linked-list

I want to create a remove node function that deletes the node at the location given at a count of my LinkedList in python. I know python has a built in garbage remover, so would my code look something like this?

```
def removeItem(self,position):
    # ListNode is a seperate file I referenced which creates a node with data and a link.
    node = ListNode.item

    count = 0

    while count != position:
        node.link = node.link.link
        count +=1

    #Node.Link should link to the next node in the sequence.
    return node
```

Comment: How do you intend for your method to know which node to remove? You say "deletes the node at the location given at a count from the head". But your method doesn't accept a count parameter, and doesn't reference the head of the list, or do any counting. Some things to consider.

Comment: Maybe *a little* like that.  Where is the "at a count from my head" part?  Note, too, that what you want to find is the node *preceding* the one to delete, and apply `node.link = node.link.link` to that node.

Comment: Sorry guys I used an old code, here is my new code I just edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to remove a node is to create a reference to the `currentNode` and `previousNode` like below.

```
def removeItem(self,position):
    currentNode = ListNode
    previousNode = None
    count = 0

    while count != position:
        #quick check to make sure next node is not empty
        if currentNode.link == None:
            print("Position Invalid")
            return None

        previousNode = currentNode
        currentNode = currentNode.link      
        count +=1

    #Node.Link should link to the next node in the sequence.
    previousNode.link = currentNode.link 
    return currentNode
```

Basically the `previousNode.link = currentNode.link` is using the previousNode's next link to reference the currentNode's next link, thus the currentNode (node you wish to remove [the node in the middle]) will lose reference and eventually be picked up by the garbage collector.

Comment: you're very welcome! Make sure you really understand LinkedList. It's a really important data structure which can easily be adjusted into other data structures like a Stack or a Queue. Now go practice! :)